# Getting Could not emit tick 0 due to lack of requests (interval doesn't support small downstream requests that replenish slower than the ticks)

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am consuming a public API with reactive WebClient. I want to call API and save the newest data from there in each 1 hour. The problem occurs when I am adding `.repeatWhen()` method to the `Flux` stream like below:

```
@Service
public class Covid19APIService {

  @Value("${rapid-API-URL}")
  private String covidAPIURL;

  @Value("${x-rapidapi-host}")
  private String covidAPI;

  @Value("${x-rapidapi-key}")
  private String covidAPIKey;

  private WebClient buildWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(covidAPIURL)
        .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs(this::acceptedCodecs).build())
        .defaultHeaders(
            httpHeaders -> {
              httpHeaders.add("x-rapidapi-host", covidAPI);
              httpHeaders.add("x-rapidapi-key", covidAPIKey);
            })
        .build();
  }

  public Flux<CountryCasesHistoryWrapper> findCasesHistoryForCountryAndDate1(
      String country, String date) {

     return buildWebClient()
        .get()
        .uri(
            builder ->
                builder
                    .path("/history_by_particular_country_by_date.php")
                    .queryParam("country", country)
                    .queryParam("date", date)
                    .build())
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(
            HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
            response -> error(new InfrastructureException("Covid19 public API not found")))
        .onStatus(
            HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
            response -> error(new InfrastructureException("Covid19 public API server exception")))
        .bodyToMono(CountryCasesHistoryWrapper.class)
             .repeatWhen(interval -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofMinutes(10)))
             .single()
          .repeatWhen(interval -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(30))).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
  }

  private void acceptedCodecs(ClientCodecConfigurer clientCodecConfigurer) {
    clientCodecConfigurer
        .customCodecs()
        .register(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_HTML));
    clientCodecConfigurer
        .customCodecs()
        .register(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_HTML));
  }
}
```

and handler method:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getCasesHistoryForCountryAndDate1(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    String country =
        serverRequest
            .queryParam("country")
            .orElseThrow(
                () -> new InfrastructureException("Country parameter is required for this action"));

    String date =
        serverRequest
            .queryParam("date")
            .orElseThrow(
                () -> new InfrastructureException("Date parameter is required for this action"));

    final Flux<CountryCasesHistoryWrapper> casesHistoryForCountryAndDate =
        apiService.findCasesHistoryForCountryAndDate1(country, date);

    return casesHistoryForCountryAndDate
        .flatMap(
            countryCasesHistoryWrapper ->
                repository.saveAll(countryCasesHistoryWrapper.getStatsByCountry()))
        .collectList()
        .flatMap(
            countryCasesHistories ->
                ServerResponse.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(countryCasesHistories)));
}
```

Above implementation leads to the exception:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit tick 0 due to lack of requests (interval doesn't support small downstream requests that replenish slower than the ticks)
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:231) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
```

I noticed similar question [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520084/spring-webflux-reactor-error-when-zipwith-could-not-emit-tick-due-to-lack-o) but despite adding `delayElements()` method exception is still occurring. Here comes the question, how to fix the current implementation and reach the desired goal which is calling API in each hour and get the newest data from there. I will be grateful for all suggestions.