# Getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type ServerRequest in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Due to the fact that I still did not find out a fully satisfying and reactive solution for my topic: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254670/getting-could-not-emit-tick-0-due-to-lack-of-requests-interval-doesnt-support), which the main assumption was:

```
How to run a Web Flux method cyclically in a reactive way?
```

I found a walkaround to make it real using the `@Scheduled` annotation. Implementation below:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Covid19APIHandler {

  private Covid19APIService apiService;

  private CountryCasesHistoryRepository repository;

  private CountryCasesWrapperRepository countryCasesWrapperRepository;

  private ServerRequest serverRequest;

  public Mono<Void> getCountryCasesAndSave(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return apiService
        .findCasesByCountry()
        .flatMap(
            wrapper ->
                countryCasesWrapperRepository
                    .save(
                        CountryCasesWrapper.builder()
                            .countries_stat(wrapper.getCountries_stat())
                            .statistic_taken_at(wrapper.getStatistic_taken_at())
                            .build())
                    .then(Mono.empty()));
  }

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
  public void casesByCountryScheduled() {
    getCountryCasesAndSave(serverRequest);
  }
}
```

The problem is that while code execution I am receiving an error:

```
Description:

Parameter 3 of constructor in com.covid.application.Covid19APIHandler required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest' in your configuration.
```

I tried `final` keyword with `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, generating all args. constructor via `IntelliJ` but still, my `ServerRequest` field is not initialized. Here comes the question, how to create my custom bean of `ServerRequest` and make it initialized properly. I will be grateful for suggestions on how to make it real.

Comment: You cannot. There is no such thing as a request scope in WebFlux. But why do you even need the request? You aren't using it anywhere in the method.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are right. I added ServerRequest by accident to make my method visible in `RouterFunction` method which was completely redundant in that case. Thanks for pointing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, why do you even need a `ServerRequest`, you arn't even using it. Remove it and clean up the code.

```
@Component
public class Covid19APIHandler {

    private Covid19APIService apiService;
    private CountryCasesWrapperRepository countryCasesWrapperRepository;

    @Autowire
    public Covid19APIHandler(Covid19APIService apiService, CountryCasesHistoryRepository repository) {
        this.apiService = apiService;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void casesByCountryScheduled() {
        apiService.findCasesByCountry()
            .flatMap(response ->
                return countryCasesWrapperRepository.save(
                    CountryCasesWrapper.builder()
                        .countries_stat(response.getCountries_stat())
                        .statistic_taken_at(response.getStatistic_taken_at())
                        .build()))
        .subscribe();
    }
}
```

In this code, your scheduled task will run in accordance to the `fixedDelay` if you want it to run each hour i recommend setting a `cron` job in the scheduler.

The code will run because of the `subscribe`. You see when you call `subscribe` you are basically running the code. The `consumer` should always be the `subscriber`. You application is a `consumer` of another application. So your service initiates the request by calling subscribe, this will start the flow of making a request and storing it in your database.

I suggest reading up on the the following

cron job with `@Scheduled`

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled

Cron syntax

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Nothing happens until you subscribe (reactor documentation)

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe