# Flux delayElements without initial delay

Tags: java, project-reactor

I would like to emit elements where elements are delayed each other by some time without initial delay.

I can not use

```
Flux.delayElements(Duration)
```

because it delays initial delay before first element which is not expected in my case.

Consider having example

```
Flux.range(1, n)
```

I would like to have below scenario:

1 delay 2 delay 3 delay ...

Current version of `Flux.delayElements` work like this:

delay 1 delay 2 delay 3 ...

My current workaround

```
Flux.interval(
    Duration.ZERO,
        Duration.ofSeconds(1)
        )
// make some call
```

but it cause problem similar to:
[Spring WebFlux (reactor). Error when zipWith - Could not emit tick due to lack of requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520084/spring-webflux-reactor-error-when-zipwith-could-not-emit-tick-due-to-lack-o?rq=1)

Could you suggest some other solution for this case or maybe there should be raised issue to introduce new method in `Flux` to cover it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Mono.delay()` to control delay.

```
@Test
void test() {
    var stream = Flux.range(1, 10)
            .concatMap(i -> 
                    Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(i))
                            .thenReturn(i)
            )
            .log();

    StepVerifier.create(stream)
            .thenConsumeWhile(rec -> true)
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

Comment: right, starting looping from 0 can give me first delay equals 0 which is expected behavior.